# Need a good way to detect presence of cabal-dev

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a bash script that runs my package's test suite and it currently looks like this:

```
cabal configure -f testing --builddir=$BUILDDIR
cabal build --builddir=$BUILDDIR --ghc-options="-Wall -Werror"
```

I only want to do that if not in a cabal-dev sand boxed environment otherwise I want to use cabal-dev instead. How would check for such a condition in a bash script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `cabal-dev` is used in the current project, there will be a `cabal-dev/` directory in the root of that project that contains the sandbox files. You can therefore check for the existence of said directory to determine whether `cabal-dev` is being used.

```bsh
if [ -d "$PROJECTDIR/cabal-dev" ]
then
    # Use cabal-dev
else
    # Use cabal
fi
```